# Как настроить автоматическое форматирование кода в vs code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Чтобы не нажимать каждый раз SHIFT+ALT+F. А при редактировании кода он сам автоматически форматировался. У меня уже такое было, но у vscode слетели настройки и плагины, забыл как настроить.

PS    Settings->

```
    editor.formatOnType - Format после ввода строки
    editor.formatOnSave - Format на сохранении
    editor.formatOnPaste - Format на вставку.
```

не помогает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Найболее популярная штука - Prettier.  его можно настроить форматировать по сохранению документа.
[prettier](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=esbenp.prettier-vscode)
Добавляешь в  корень проекта файл `.prettierrc`
с нужными параметрами, например:

```
{
  "printWidth": 80,
  "tabWidth": 4,
  "useTabs": false,
  "semi": true,
  "singleQuote": true,
  "trailingComma": "all",
  "bracketSpacing": true,
  "jsxBracketSameLine": false,
  "arrowParens": "always"
}
```